# Nginx and uwsgi issue (implementation on EC2)

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm using ec2 + uwsgi + django to set up the website on Amazion AWS, using instructions from: http://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html . It works perfectly till I reach the step where  i am trying to run the uwsgi with socket

wsgi --socket mysite.sock --wsgi-file test.py' or 'uwsgi --socket mysite.sock --wsgi-file test.py --chmod-socket=666

(other than http, and we haven't use uwsgi.ini yet, just purely command), we get the error cannot open python file. Not sure why this is happening

Here is the log:

```
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
failed to open python file wsgi.py
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 32084, cores: 1)
```

Update

We used the same procedure on ubuntu machine and it worked out just fine!

Comment: can you post the error message with logs?

Comment: Just added it the log as requested

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. You have to make sure you source your `virtualenv` before you run `uwsgi`

```
virtualenv uwsgi-tutorial
cd uwsgi-tutorial
source bin/activate
```

Are you sure the content of `test.py` is not using `wsgi` in it ?

For example, if you look at this other post: [Django, uWSGI, gevent loop - How to get to get to work - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218799/django-uwsgi-gevent-loop-how-to-get-to-get-to-work-unable-to-load-app-0-m), the user has a `wsgi.py` file that is making use of the `wsgi` class.

[Edit]

Since you are not using a virtualenv. Make sure the you don't have any uwsgi installations that are conflicting with your uwsgi module.  How did you installed uwsgi ? Using pip ? or using the system ? Make sure your uwsgi executable is under `/usr/local/bin` (if you installed it using pip)

You can also try removing the system uwsgi:

```
sudo apt-get remove uwsgi uwsgi-core
```

and reinstalling uwsgi:

```
pip uninstall uwsgi
pip install uwsgi
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: We are not using virtualenv to implement. just doing it in default env  ...i thought that should be easier

Comment: I added some tips.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Is necesarry use virtualenv to run wsgi?, so i'm using docker.

Comment: @juliansalas no.  you can use it separately if you'd like